# Replace element of a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, replace

I have list and i want to replace all the elements os the list with another elements.
Code:

```
list1 = ['1','1','3','4','5','2','3','4']                                           
dict1 = {'dict1' : ['1','2','3','4','5'] ,'name':['su5','pra4','sa3','ma2','sri1']}            
for x in range(len(dict1['dict1'])):    
      list1 = [word.replace(dict1['dict1'][x],dict1['name'][x]) for word in list1]   
print(list1)
```

Actual Output:

```
['susri1', 'susri1', 'sa3', 'ma2', 'sri1', 'prama2', 'sa3', 'ma2']
```

Expected Output:

```
['su5','su5','sa3','ma2','sri1','pra4','sa3','ma2']
```

Comment: What if an element is `'12'`? Do you want to rename it to `su5pra4`?

Comment: No I don't want to rename as su5pra4.

Answer (score 4):

That's a very strange dictionary if you transform the dictionary so you can use it as a direct mapping then this is a relatively easy thing to do, e.g.:

```
>>> dict2 = dict(zip(dict1['dict1'], dict1['name']))
>>> [dict2[i] for i in list1]
['su5', 'su5', 'sa3', 'ma2', 'sri1', 'pra4', 'sa3', 'ma2']
```